# Error message assertion failure with message: "read"

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, nodeos

I made my own smart contract. and tried to erase my table. But it didn't. 
I will attach the following error

```
{
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal Service Error",
  "error": {
    "code": 3050003,
    "name": "eosio_assert_message_exception",
    "what": "eosio_assert_message assertion failure",
    "details": [{
        "message": "assertion failure with message: read",
        "file": "wasm_interface.cpp",
        "line_number": 926,
        "method": "eosio_assert"
      },{
        "message": "pending console output: ",
        "file": "apply_context.cpp",
        "line_number": 75,
        "method": "exec_one"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

the "read" error message is occurred in datastream.

Wasm file is stored in database and executed by transaction(method : exec_one). 
But How do error occur in datastream?

Comment: Do you have some code like `check(..., "read")` in your contract?

Comment: No.. whether a code ``check(...)`` exist , the same error is occurred

Comment: Could you provide the code from the contract that is causing this issue. We got the error but without the source context there isn't much we can help you with right now.